# Connect iPad Applications using Flash to a local database?

Tags: database, ipad, flash, local

I am currently creating a quiz application, which will send data between two different applications on the iPad. Is there a way to connect two Flash CS6 applications together via a local database? These flash applications will be used on iPads.

It is very important that the information is not accessible online.

Comment: consider put some code, could help you get an answer

Answer (score 1):

As I recall iOS is very much sand-boxed to where you can't share a local database between 2 Apps.

You could look into assigning your apps different URL prefixes / schemes, but I am unsure how well Flash supports setting those up. If you get it to work though, then you could theoretically maintain one local database per app and communicate between the apps using the URL prefixes. Of course maintaining and syncing 2 separate database may turn out to a pain.

Really the solution I would lean toward is to store the common database on a server that does not have a front end to it, just a simple API. This would prevent users from accessing the data online while allowing any number of apps to access it at will. If you ever expand into Android or other mobile platforms this would allow the same data to be readily sharable as well.

Comment: Hi Todd.

I understand your first section, about it being Sand-boxed.

I don't really understand the second part. How would I go about doing this and would this allow two seperate iPad applications to connect and share data?

Comment: If you were doing a native iOS App you could use URL Schemes http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/ but I don't Think Flash has a way for you to do that. Like I said, storing the database on the server is the way I'd go.